# C, reading multiple numbers from single input line

Tags: arrays, c, csv

I need to create a c program that handles many cases.

In order to solve all the cases easily i need to take all the input elements in one line separated by a comma.

for example user given input like this

```
5,60,700,8000
```

should create an array like this `{5,,,60,,,700,,,8000}`
which means array is of size 7 and a[1],a[3],a[5] value is comma ,

thank you

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit***:  There are actually *several* ways to do what you are asking: array of struct (may contain several data types), array of struct with union (allows run-time selection of data type), string array (requires converting numeric values)

<strike>The only way to *literally* construct an array to hold both numeric and string variable types is to use a `union`.</strike>  Clearly (and normally) there are much better ways to handle strings of alphanumeric data, but since unions were mentioned in the comments under your question, I will use that method to address your very specific request:

Results of following example:
[image]

Code example:

```
typedef union   {
    int num;      //member to contain numerics
    char str[4];  //member to contain string (",,,")
}MIX;
typedef struct  {
    BOOL type;//type tag:  1 for char , 0 for number
    MIX c;
}ELEMENT;

ELEMENT element[7], *pElement;//instance of array 7 of ELEMENT and pointer to same

void assignValues(ELEMENT *e);

int main(void)
{
    char buf[80];//buffer for printing out demonstration results
    buf[0]=0;
    int i;

    pElement = &element[0];//initialize pointer to beginning of struct element

    //assign values to array:
    assignValues(pElement);

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(element)/sizeof(element[0]);i++)
    {
        if(pElement[i].type == 1)
        {   //if union member is a string, concatenate it to buffer
            strcpy(element[i].c.str, pElement[i].c.str);
            strcat(buf,pElement[i].c.str); 
        }
        else
        {   //if union member is numeric, convert and concatenate it to buffer
            sprintf(buf, "%s%d",buf, pElement[i].c.num); 
        }
    }
    printf(buf);

    getchar();

    return 0;   
}

//hardcoded to illustrate your exact numbers
// 5,,,60,,,700,,,8000
void assignValues(ELEMENT *e)
{
    e[0].type = 0; //fill with 5
    e[0].c.num = 5;

    e[1].type = 1; //fill with ",,,"
    strcpy(e[1].c.str, ",,,");

    e[2].type = 0; //fill with 60
    e[2].c.num = 60;

    e[3].type = 1; //fill with ",,,"
    strcpy(e[3].c.str, ",,,");

    e[4].type = 0; //fill with 700
    e[4].c.num = 700;

    e[5].type = 1;  //fill with ",,,"
    strcpy(e[5].c.str, ",,,");

    e[6].type = 0; //fill with 8000
    e[6].c.num = 8000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to store the `,`. Use something similar to

```
int a[4];
scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3]);
```

If you need to put the commas back for printing later you can use

```
printf("%d,%d,%d,%d", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. But in my program i want to allow only comma in between the inputs.so its required to store the comma in array so that we can put some condition like a[1]=',' and terminate the program if its not

Comment: @user1934439 - so your array will need to store strings, not numeric values, in that case (that, or a union of an `int` and a `char`, with a tag) - is that acceptable for your purposes?

Comment: @user1934439 That's not specified in your question and presents a completely different problem.

Comment: yes no problem. my requirement is array must be only of length 7 in which a[0] a[2] a[4] a[6] must be only numbers and a[1] a[3] a[5] must be only comma.

Comment: @IKavanagh i dont have much knowledge in c programming. i studied long ago in my bachelors. can you put whole code of my requirement if possible